# Convergence of a product under the trace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, trace

Let $A$ be a fixed matrix $n\times n$ matrix, and let $B_k$ be a sequence of $n\times n$ matrix such that $B_k$ converges to the identity matrix $I$. Suppose you have established this rate of convergence under the spectral norm (or any other matrix norm that is convenient).

**Question**: how is the rate of convergence related to the rate of convergence of $\text{tr}(AB_k)\to \text{tr}(A)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = U \Sigma V^*$ be the singular value decomposition of $A$.
Then 
$$|\text{tr}(A (B_k - I))| =  |\text{tr}(\Sigma V^* (B_k - I) U) |
\le \text{tr}(\Sigma) \|B_k - I\|$$

where $\text{tr}(\Sigma)$ is the sum of the singular values of $A$.
Moreover, this is best possible (it's an equality if $V^*(B_k-I)U$ is a multiple of the identity).

Comment: I accepted your answer, but I do have a doubt about something that I guess is rather basic. I understand that since $\Sigma$ is diagonal you get an inequality by pulling out $\text{tr}(\Sigma)$. However, how do you justify pulling out the spectral norm of $B_k-I$?

Comment: $|\text{tr}(\Sigma B)|  = \left|\sum_i \sigma_i B_{ii}\right| \le \|B\| \sum_i \sigma_i$ since $|B_{ii}| = | e_i^T B e_i| \le \|B\|$.

Answer (score 1):

$$|\text{tr}(A (B_k - I))| \leq \Vert A\Vert_{1} \|B_k - I\|_{\infty}  $$ where $\|.\|_{\infty}$ is spectral norm, and $\Vert .\Vert_{1}$ trace norm

for more information, suggest you Appendix D of abstract Harmonic Analysis by hewitt

Comment: The spectral norm is the 2-norm, not the $\infty$ norm. And the reference is rather abstruse.

Comment: you are right i have used the symbol of hewitt

Comment: You are saying that in Hewitt the infinity norm is actually the spectral norm? It would be nice if you cited an exact theorem and showed exactly how this comes from it. D49 doesn't seem to imply this as far as I can tell.

Comment: page 703. where he introduce $\|E\|_{\varphi_p}$